# php html decode string

Tags: php

I have an array which returns various strings which I'm trying to html-decode. But I can't seem to find a function which will work on all the strings. For example, one of my strings looks like this:

```
"a detail of The School of Athens<!-- this should link to an article about the famous artwork -->, a fresco by Raphael"
```

While the other looks like this:

```
""Aristotle" by Francesco Hayez (1791â€“1882)"
```

I can either use `html_entity_decode` to get rid of the comment (`<!--/-->`) in the first string, or `htmlentities` in the second to change the `â€“` to a `-`, but I can't find anything that will change ALL my strings to regular text. Is there a function that can do this?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>String Cleansing</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo '<pre>';

// The below are the strings
echo $string_with_htmlent =
     "a detail of The School of Athens<!-- this should link to an article about the famous artwork -->, a fresco by Raphael";

echo '<br>';

echo $string_unicode = 
     "Aristotle by Francesco Hayez (1791";
?>&acirc;&euro;&quot;
<?php 

echo $string_unicode_c = "1882)";    
echo '<br>';

// The below is how you fixed
echo $a = html_entity_decode($string_with_htmlent); echo '<br>';

echo $b = htmlentities($string_unicode.$string_unicode_c);

echo '<br>';

// The below is how I code and you expect
$clean = $string_with_htmlent.' '.$string_unicode.' '.$string_unicode_c; 

var_dump(filter_var($clean,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

echo '</pre>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternate for `html_entity_decode` and `htmlentities` is `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`. Fixing all html entity codes and special characters with one built-in function.